# Detect mouse position with respect to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor-position

I have drawn a rectangle using svg in html. I need to detect the cursor position on the screen with respect to this rectangle and change its style. 
I need to do something like this:

```
if (cursor is left to the rectangle) {
    background of rectangle = red;
}
else if (cursor is right to the rectangle) {
    background of rectangle = blue;
}
```

how to determine the position of the cursor wrt the rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the thing you want with jQuery

CSS:

```
body {
  cursor:pointer;
}

td {
  border:#777 1px solid;
  font-family:georgia; font-size:50px;
}

#content {
  background:green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="left"/> (left)<br/>
<input id="width"/> (width)<br/>
<input id="pageX"/> (pageX)<br/>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Left</td>
    <td id="content">Center</td>
    <td>Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var content = $("#content");
    var left  = content.offset().left;
    var width = content.width();
    var pageX = event.pageX;

    $("#left").get(0).value = left;
    $("#width").get(0).value = width;
    $("#pageX").get(0).value = pageX;

    if (pageX<left)
      content.css({"background":"red"});
    else
    if (pageX>left+width)
      content.css({"background":"blue"});
    else
      content.css({"background":"green"});
  });
});
```

See the full HTML, CSS, JS in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/95te26q6/

Comment: Thanks Jon! This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 (function() {
        window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var rect = $("#rect");
             var left  = rect.position().left;
            var width = rect.width();
            var Xpos=event.clientX;
            if (Xpos<left)
                rect.css({"background":"red"});
              else
              if (Xpos>left+width)
                  rect.css({"background":"blue"});

        }
    })();
 });
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Left</td>
    <td id="rect">Center</td>
    <td>Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```